# Change Integer Value first time App Is Opened

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I wanted to give a value to an integer just the first time the user opens the App. I managed to do it using this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DidOpenBefore"]) {
    NSLog(@"didOpenBefore");
    intNo = intNo;
}else{
    intNo = 5;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DidOpenBefore"];
}
```

And it does work, but as soon as I run it for the second time, the value is 0, why is it happening? It should stick with the value I gave it (5) right? If I am doing something wrong or if you can help me in any possible way I would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would it have the value 5?  You set the value to `BOOL` (`YES`).

Comment: **the value is 0,** of what ? the question is little confusing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save your int value into user defaults

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
         if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DidOpenBefore"]) {
            NSLog(@"didOpenBefore");
            intNo = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"intNo"] intValue] ;
        }else{
            intNo = 5;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intNo] forKey:@"intNo"]; 
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DidOpenBefore"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
```

Comment: this fixed the issue. Thank you very much Alexander, you just have a typo "valueforkey:forkey" please fix it, as it may confuse people with the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `intNo = intNo;` to get a previous stored value. You must store it somewhere (User Defaults, Plist, SQL, etc) then read the value from there.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a special method to do this, the method is -[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:], the best place to put this is in the +(void)initialize method of your application delegate like such

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    [[NSUserDefault standardDefaults] registerDefaults:<a dictionary of the initial value>];
}
```

These values are only used if there are not found within the user default property list for you app.

I will often create a plist file for my project called InitialUserDefaults and then in my initialise method load it as a dictionary and seed the UserDefaults that way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your defaults saved result immediately, You have to **synchronize** the default after setting it.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DidOpenBefore"];  
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

NOTE:
you have to store int in defaults so next time you will get that.rather than bool.

Comment: I don't understand why the vote down, I mean, we're all here to help each other, and you were trying to help.
Regarding your answer, that is not the issue, I think that we don't even need to synchronize anymore cause the OS will eventually do that for us.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is not helpful. It does not solve the problem and enforces the "synchronize all the things" meme that is flat wrong. synchronizing is not the answer to all NSUserDefault problems. To get the rep penalty back, delete the answer.

Comment: @Mykod:leave it,, tell you have to store `int` in defaults so next time you will get that.rather than bool?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: updated answer ,as i know , You must need `synchronize` if you want to get result immediately,i know os will save it but it will not save immediately.